# types createReducerManager

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

can someone helps me rewrite this function for injected reducer from the official documentation to typescript? https://redux.js.org/usage/code-splitting

How the correct way to create `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types

In bassicaly i do next:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

But when i created store with createReducerManager function types not working

createReducerManager function:

```
export function createReducerManager(initialReducers) {
  // Create an object which maps keys to reducers
  const reducers = { ...initialReducers }

  // Create the initial combinedReducer
  let combinedReducer = combineReducers(reducers)

  // An array which is used to delete state keys when reducers are removed
  let keysToRemove = []

  return {
    getReducerMap: () => reducers,

    // The root reducer function exposed by this object
    // This will be passed to the store
    reduce: (state, action) => {
      // If any reducers have been removed, clean up their state first
      if (keysToRemove.length > 0) {
        state = { ...state }
        for (let key of keysToRemove) {
          delete state[key]
        }
        keysToRemove = []
      }

      // Delegate to the combined reducer
      return combinedReducer(state, action)
    },

    // Adds a new reducer with the specified key
    add: (key, reducer) => {
      if (!key || reducers[key]) {
        return
      }

      // Add the reducer to the reducer mapping
      reducers[key] = reducer

      // Generate a new combined reducer
      combinedReducer = combineReducers(reducers)
    },

    // Removes a reducer with the specified key
    remove: key => {
      if (!key || !reducers[key]) {
        return
      }

      // Remove it from the reducer mapping
      delete reducers[key]

      // Add the key to the list of keys to clean up
      keysToRemove.push(key)

      // Generate a new combined reducer
      combinedReducer = combineReducers(reducers)
    }
  }
}

const staticReducers = {
  users: usersReducer,
  posts: postsReducer
}

export function configureStore(initialState) {
  const reducerManager = createReducerManager(staticReducers)

  // Create a store with the root reducer function being the one exposed by the manager.
  const store = createStore(reducerManager.reduce, initialState)

  // Optional: Put the reducer manager on the store so it is easily accessible
  store.reducerManager = reducerManager
}
```